# How can we use the ternary operator with multiple condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The below piece of code working but to simplify the code, how can we use the ternary operator ?

```
function fnOnChangeType() {

    if (document.RequestHistoryForm.strMessageType.value=="All") {
        document.getElementById("selectMessageView").disabled=false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("selectMessageView").disabled=true;
    }
}

function fnOnChangeView() {
    if (document.RequestHistoryForm.strMessageView.value=="") {
        document.getElementById("selectMessageType").disabled=false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("selectMessageType").disabled=true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need of a ternary here :

```
function fnOnChangeType() { 
    document.getElementById("selectMessageView").disabled = document.RequestHistoryForm.strMessageType.value !== "All";
}

function fnOnChangeView() {
    document.getElementById("selectMessageType").disabled = document.RequestHistoryForm.strMessageView.value !== "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can shortened it by doing this;

```
function fnOnChangeType() {
    document.getElementById("selectMessageView").disabled = document.RequestHistoryForm.strMessageType.value !== "All";
}
function fnOnChangeView() {
    document.getElementById("selectMessageType").disabled = document.RequestHistoryForm.strMessageView.value !== "";
}
```

Comment: Instead of negating an equality operation, you can just use an inequality one i.e. `!==`

Comment: yeah or you can copy paste my answer now :D

Answer (score 2):

Syntax for ternary operation in JS :

```
 var statement = expression1 ? value1 : value2 ; 
    // If expression is true,then return value1, 
    // otherwise return value2;
```

Try :

`document.getElementById("selectMessageView").disabled = document.RequestHistoryForm.strMessageType.value=="All" ? false : true`;

Comment: And shorter: 

document.getElementById("selectMessageView").disabled = !document.RequestHistoryForm.strMessageType.value == "All";


OR 
document.getElementById("selectMessageView").disabled = document.RequestHistoryForm.strMessageType.value != "All";

Comment: @SleepyPanda : Absolutely. This is a short and good solution. Since the question explicitly mentioned about ternary operator , I provided a solution with ternary operation

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, which I probably wouldn't use for only two sets like this, but would if there are three or more, is to write a generic version to reuse:

```
function enableFieldOnValue(fieldToEnable, testField, value) {
  document.getElementById(fieldToEnable).disabled = 
    document.RequestHistoryForm[testField].value == value
}

enableFieldOnValue("selectMessageView", "strMessageType", "All")
enableFieldOnValue("selectMessageType", "strMessageView", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can get is this:

```
fnOnChangeType = ()=>
    document.getElementById("selectMessageView").disabled = 
        document.RequestHistoryForm.strMessageType.value != "All"
fnOnChangeView = ()=>
    document.getElementById("selectMessageType").disabled =    
        document.RequestHistoryForm.strMessageView.value != ""
```

The use of the ternary operator would be worst in this case, because you would only lengthen the function with an unecessary `? false : true` suffix, when if you just invert the condition you can simplify the line. Take a look:

```
fnOnChangeType = ()=>
    document.getElementById("selectMessageView").disabled = 
        (document.RequestHistoryForm.strMessageType.value == "All" ? false : true;
fnOnChangeView = ()=>
    document.getElementById("selectMessageType").disabled =    
        document.RequestHistoryForm.strMessageView.value == "" ? false : true;
```

You make it more readable if you put the objects in variables:

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectMessageView"),
    requestHistoryForm = document.RequestHistoryForm;

fnOnChangeType = ()=> select.disabled = requestHistoryForm.strMessageType.value != "All";
fnOnChangeView = ()=> select.disabled = requestHistoryForm.strMessageView.value != "";
```